# Vagrant ERROR: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vagrant

I was trying to get my own Virtual Machine running while reading the documentation about getting started with Vagrant and I set my first virtual machine. I am using Vagrant with VirtualBox, but after I 'vagrant destroy' I can't seem to get it running again as I get the next error: "apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName"

I tried Googling this problem and I think that I have to set my ServerName as localhost, but I didn't find how to do this within my VM.

I tried to set ServerName = localhost both in my Vagrantfile and the bootstrap.sh file.

## My Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.box_version = "1.1.0"
  config.vm.box_url = "https://vagrantcloud.com/hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 4567

end
```

## My bootstrap.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

apt-get update
apt-get install -y apache2
if ! [ -L /var/www ]; then
  rm -rf /var/www
  ln -fs /vagrant /var/www
fi
```

I didn't expect to get an error as it was just working after setting up my VM.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried Googling this problem and I think that I have to set my ServerName as localhost, but I didn't find how to do this within my VM.

Since this is an Apache error, this typically is done in your Apache configuration file. Open e.g. `httpd.conf` (or whatever equivalent you have) on your VM and find the `ServerName` entry. Set it to something like:

```
ServerName www.example.com
```

In this case `www.example.com` can be anything you choose (including `www.example.com`). That is, the domain name you enter doesn't have to be valid. Save `httpd.conf`, restart Apache and the warning you are seeing should be suppressed.